# General Question: Why is text based search more costly/expensive than other fields in a database table?

Tags: sql, search, text, shopify

On Shopify, I noticed there is no capability to search on the Notes text in a Sales Order.  However, all other fields, you can search even by wildcard.

I assume Shopify does not offer text based search on the Notes text.  I know it's expensive but in terms of technical concepts, I am not sure why and was hoping someone could explain to me?

Answer (score 0):

Every time there is a query involving a FULLTEXT index, the MySQL Query Optimizer tends to whack the query into a full table scan. I have seen this over the years. The full table scan is what's taking the time in a FULLTEXT search Also, [here is a post that I found from a separate answer that may dive into the technicalities a bit further for your understanding.](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/11716/mysql-fulltext-search-my-cnf-optimization/11730#11730)

Hope this helps!